# Java - Generate a series of possible coordinates

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm sorry for the poor wording of the question, but it is the best way I can think of asking this question.

I've initialised a Hashmap (hm) and I'm wanting to use it to store some objects called LandPlots which take x and y coordinates when being called.

Example:

`hm.put(new LandPlot(0,0),0);` will create a LandPlot at '0,0'

`hm.put(new LandPlot(0,1),1);` will create a LandPlot at '0,1'

I want to do this with a loop that will go and create enough 'LandPlot' objects to fill an 8x6 'Game board'.

I've tried doing this with the following loop:

```
for (x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
            hm.put(new LandPlot(x, y), i);
            System.out.println(hm.values());
            i++;
        }
    }
```

(Where 'x','y' and 'i' are all initialised as '0')

Now, I'm certain of two things:

1) What I'm after should be stupidly simple; I'm sure that I've done something simialr before for picture manipulation in Jython with loops, but I cannot for the life of me remember a term to properly describe it, thus making it hard to find the info I'm looking for online.

2) I'm super new to Hashmaps, and I doubt that `hm.values()` is the proper way of quickly showing whether or not it has worked.

If there is any more info I can provide, let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Doug.

Comment: 1) Those are standard Java loops; not much to say, and not sure what is being asked. Java (although Java 8 changes it a bit) simply isn't as expressive as [J]Python. 2) No; but does it "work"? If not, *why* not? (If the code "isn't working" then there is likely an issue with LandPlot having a broken `hashCode/equals` implementation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing LandPlot as key and not as value. 
Try`hm.put(i, new LandPlot(x,y));` instead.

Answer (score 0):

All good now, thanks guys.

I combined the info from both answers, and ended up with this loop:

```
for(y = 0; y < 6;  y++)
    {
          for(x = 0; x < 8; x++)
          {
                hm.put(i, new LandPlot(x, y));
                System.out.println(hm.get(i));
                i++;
        }
    }
```

And, after I created getters for `x` and `y`, I Overrode `toString()` in `LandPlot` to return:

```
return ("Land Plot at "+LandStore.getX()+","+LandStore.getY());
```

Thanks again,

Doug.